# RStudio Presentationで文字化け

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudioのPresentation機能を使ってスライドを作成しています。
OS Windows7
RStudio ver. 0.99.491（最新）

Global/Project OptionのEncodingはUTF8です。

文字コードの選択につき、以下のような問題に悩んでいます。

1.ソースのrpresファイルでSJISを選ぶと、Preview画面でフォルダ名しか表示されない
2.ソースファイルでUTF8を選ぶと、Preview画面が文字化けする（しかし、ブラウザで表示するとSJISに変更で正常に表示される。）
3.Global/Project OptionのEncodingでSJIS（CP932）を選択しても同様の症状。

Presentation Preview画面の出力のヘッダ部のプロパティをinspectでみると、Global/Project Optionの設定にかかわらず、chrset=utf-8となっており、おそらくPreviewの表示設定の問題ではないかと推測しますが、これをどう変更してよいのかわかりません。
対処方法につきご教授いただけると幸甚です。

Comment: 面白い現象を発見しました。
Rpresの新規作成でデフォルトのソースにある、summary(cars)のスライドを、削除すると文字化け、もとに戻すと文字化けも治ります。
文字化け時は、pandocのmdファイルが確かにSJISに変わっています。

Answer (score 1):

日本語Windows（厳密には、OSのロケールがUTF-8以外の環境）限定で発生する問題です。
ソースのRpresファイルでShift-JISを使うのは、HTML変換をするpandocがUTF-8のみのサポートなので無理です。
RpresファイルでUTF-8を使っても文字化けする問題は、https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/563 で修正が反映されているので、GitHubから最新版のRstudioのソースコードをとってビルドすれば解決します。
...ですが、それは結構大変なので、とりあえず、Rstudio上で何らかのプロジェクトを作成し、プロジェクト内でRpresファイルを作るようにすればUTF-8が文字化けする問題を回避できます。
（厳密には、プロジェクトのオプションでEncodingをUTF-8に指定する必要がありますが、デフォルトでUTF-8になっていると思います）

Comment: mokjpnさん、ありがとうございます。
すでにProjectでUTF-8の下でRpresを作っています。最初は正しく表示されるのですが、突然に文字化けが始まりまして、いったん化けると元に戻りません。
コードを加えたりすると強制的に表示の文字コードが変わっているようにも見えます。そうなると、自分でビルドするか次のバージョンを待つしかないということでしょうか。

Comment: この回答で解決しないとなると，未知の問題かもしれません．以下確認してみていただけますか？

- 化ける文字と化けない文字があったりしますか？例えばひらがなは化けない，日本語文字列の最初の方は化けない，などです．その場合はUTF-8の文字列をShift-JISとして無理やり読んでいることになります．上記のパッチは，プロジェクトが作られていない時にこういう扱いになるRstudioのバグを修正するものでしたが，他にも同様のバグが潜んでいるのかもしれません．
- .Rpresから.md のMarkdownファイルが作成されていると思いますが，この.mdファイルの中身は文字化けしていますか？

Comment: mokjpnさん。その後いろいろ試しました。
１．Global OptionとプロジェクトでUTF8をデフォルトにして新規にRpresを作るときれいに日本語が表示されます。
２．しかし、パッケージのヘルプを開くと、アクティブのRpresに急に文字化けが始まり、いったん化けると戻りません。なお、同時に開いている別のRpresは正常に表示されます。ブラウザで文字コードをSJISに変更すると正常に表示されます。
３．上記ｍｄファイルを開くと、文字化けしているほうはSJISになっていて、文字化けしていないｍｄのほうはUTF8のままです。何かが勝手にコード変換をかけているか、どこかの設定の誤りでしょうか。

Comment: 上記コメント中の具体的症状がわかりづらいので修正します。
１．Global OptionとプロジェクトでUTF8をデフォルトにして新規にRpresを作るとPreviewできれいに日本語が表示されます。 
２．しかし、何かのタイミングでいったんPreviewでの文字化けが発生しだすとRpresの文字コードを変えてもPreviewの文字化けは修復されません。
３．なお、同時に開いている別のRpresはそのままソースもPreviewも正常に表‌​示されています。
４．文字化けしたPreviewはブラウザで文字コードをSJISに変更すると正常に表示されます。 
５．上記のｍｄファイルを開いてみると、文字化けしているほうはSJISになっていて、文字化けしていないｍｄのほうはUTF8のままです。

Comment: ついでにもう一つ分かったことを追記しておきます。
Previewを実行した際に、チャンクの中で何らかのエラーがあると、エラーメッセージをSJISでMDファイルにするようです。表示はUTF8なので当然に文字化けになります。